# Qt project hierarchy

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qmake, project-organization

I need to make hierarchy for this example. Base and Components is directories with headers and sources. What template I need to use in place of `???` ? What template use in these directories ?

```
App(???)
--Base
--Component1
--Component2
--Component3
CLI(app)
GUI(app)
test(app)
```

Comment: What do you mean by template? Your question is unclear.

Comment: @Nejat I mean Qt template subdirs, lib, app...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a Subdirs project and add the subprojects to its .pro file :

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs

CONFIG += ordered

SUBDIRS += \
    Base \
    Component1 \
    Component2 \
    Component3 \
    CLI \
    GUI \
    test
```

You should bring the subprojects that others depend on, first in the list. Also notice that the name of the .pro file of the subproject should be the same as it's folder name. This way the subprojects are detected and listed in the Projects pane.

The subprojects Base, Component1, Component2 and Component3 could be libraries. Part of .pro file for Base :

```
TARGET = Base
TEMPLATE = lib

DEFINES += Base_LIBRARY

SOURCES += ...
HEADERS += ...
```

The subprojects CLI, GUI and test should be app. Part of .pro file for GUI :

```
TARGET = GUI
TEMPLATE = app
```

You can use the libraries in each subproject by linking it to the subproject. This can be done by right clicking on the subproject and choosing "Add Library" and then "Internal Library". When you select one library from the list of subprojects, the linking configurations are added to the .pro automatically. It will be like :

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$OUT_PWD/../Base/release/ -lBase
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$OUT_PWD/../Base/debug/ -lBase
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$OUT_PWD/../Base/ -lBase

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../Base
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../Base
```

Comment: I need to use Component 1 code in Base. How to make lib(of App) just with subdirectories.

Comment: OK bring Component1 before Base in the list and link Component1 to Base. I didn't get what you mean by "How to make lib(of App) just with subdirectories"

Comment: OK, I how to link Component to Base ?

Comment: Just right click on the Base subproject in the Project Pane and choose "Add Library" and then "Internal Library". After clicking next select component1 from the list. Click next and finish.